# how to match integers inside a single line string

Tags: regex

Looking for a pattern in `ECMAScript` flavor to find all integers
positive, like `+1`,
negative like `-1`,
and implicit-positive like `1`
inside a single line, like:

```
0 zero +1 2.2 1.1 -1 -1.1 one 1
```

and **NOT** multi-line, like:

```
0
zero
+1
1.1
etc, ...
```

Therefore, for this line, the pattern should match: (`0 +1 -1 1`)

```
0 zero +1 2.2 1.1 -1 -1.1 one 1
^      ^^         ^^          ^
```

based on:

1. `ECMAScript`
2. repetition is okay, so `12346789` should be match
3. if it is possible, without capturing group `()`
4. As efficient as possible

Example:
A stupid pattern like: `(?:^\d+|(?!\d)[+-]?\d+(?!\.)|\d+$)`  can match `0 +1 -1 1`
But it does not match `1` in a string like:

```
0 zero 1 two 2
^            ^
```

Because of `(?!\d)` before `+` and `-` signs

Comment: **I am not looking for a JavaScript code**

Comment: You cannot use a pattern without capturing groups, because the best pattern for this task relies on a lookbehind that ECMAScript flavor does not support. Try `reg(R"((?:^|\s)([+-]?\d+)(?!\.\d)(?!.*\r?\n))")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. Okay. how about **with** capturing group? I just said if is is possible.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/Q1mt28/1/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. It looks fine. I am just testing it. Later I will tell to post your answer. thanks.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That pattern doesn't work as intended. It doesn't reject multiline completely (which is probably impossible in ECMAScript regex), and it matches anything that starts with a number like 1one. Also, some systems have the new lines as `\r`, not `\n`.

Comment: @RacilHilan I agree that `1amy` should not be matched. https://regex101.com/r/Q1mt28/2 could be a better pattern. Still not perfect. And yes, it still matches digits on the last line of a multiline string. So, I don't think there is a pure one-regex solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
(?:^| )[+-]?\d+?(?= |$)
```

It does everything you want, except rejecting multiline. It is not possible to reject multiline in ECMAScript regex, but you can easily test for multiline and reject it before you check with the regex above using this simple regex:

```
[\n\r]+?
```

Note: you don't need to run this pattern globally; you can break at the first match (i.e. first line break), so don't use the `g` flag.

Comment: your pattern about 2-3 times faster.

Comment: Okay, Just please tell me about `?` after `\d+`. It is a lazy question mark or optional one. What does it do?

Comment: The question mark is for lazy and comes after a plus or asterisk. Lazy means it matches as few as possible. Opposite to the default plus or asterisk which are greedy and match as many as possible. In your scenario and the pattern above, it probably doesn't matter because we're restricting the numbers to be only between spaces, so you probably can remove the question mark and gain a little more performance. Similarly, in the second pattern if you follow my advice of not using the `g` flag, then you can also remove the plus and question mark and gain a little more performance.